# Permanent solution to Win XP SP3 window animation removal

Tags: windows-xp, animation, visual-effects

May I know how I can get rid of the Window Animation (seen when you minimise or maximise a window) in Windows XP Service Pack 3 Permanently‎?

I have tried the following two solutions:

1. I went to the **control panel**, **adjust visual effects**, then unchecked the "`Animate windows when maximising and minimising`" option
2. I have tried using windows powertoys tweakUI to disable the animation.
3. I even tried `Turn Off Window Animation`

   - You can shut off the animation displayed when you minimize and maximize Windows

     - Open RegEdit
     - Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control panel \Desktop\ WindowMetrics
     - Create a new string value "MinAnimate".
     - Set the value data of 0 for Off or 1 for On
   - But still no help.

The Big Problem is that the window animation will disappear for a while but returns again some time later. When I navigate back to the "adjust visual effects" window, the checkbox for "Animate windows when maximising and minimising" is checked again.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

There is a reference to [TweakUI on this XPAnnoyances site](http://xpannoyances.com/exec/show/article05-025).

- Obtain TweakUI ([Wikipedia description link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweak_UI)).

  - from [Microsoft PowerToys for XP](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx) page
- Choose the General tab, and turn off any of the following options:

  - Window Animation
  - Menu Animation
  - Combo Box Animation (drop-down listboxes)
  - Listbox Animation

Here is another reference you might like: [10 Steps to a Faster Windows XP](http://www.go2guyconsulting.com/index.php/content/view/15/44/).
Step 9 again refers TweakUI to disable animation.

TweakUI does a registry tweak which you will also find around.
You need to add a `MinAnimate` string with a zero value in,
`HKCU/.default/Control Panel/Desktop/WindowMetrics`, I think.

---

Update:
<sup>after reformatting your question, I could read it better</sup>

1. Have you confirmed administrative rights for the user you login as?
2. You are changing the HKCU key for your user identity,
   Try the `HKU` `default` path from my answer above.
3. And, it is suggested that you reboot after the edit -- did you do that?

Comment: Thanks nik. I cannot find the button to add comments to your answers. Sorry about that.

Yes. My account is the only account and it is that of an administrator. I will update you again if your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

In `[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics]` add or update the following registry key :

```
"MinAnimate"="0"
```

MinAnimate is a `REG_SZ`

Reboot immediatly.

Be careful : it is in `HKEY_USERS` not in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.